# Best practice: validating signature of currently running code with Get-AuthenticodeSignature

Tags: validation, powershell, code-signing

I am looking at using Get-AuthenticodeSignature to validate my scripts at launch, even for folks who have ExecutionPolicy set to Unrestricted. But of course I can't work and test, unless I was signing the code after every edit, which seems problematic. So I was considering adding a variable and some code that would do the validation, but I could flag a Development mode, and the validation would be skipped. My initial thought was that just makes it easy to bypass my little bit of security, but then all anyone really needs to do is delete that bit of code and the signature block, so none of this is "really" secure. Which leads me to wonder, what is the best practice, when using PowerShell for a "product", not just for in-house management?

Comment: What are you trying to "defend" against here? If you need to sign your scripts because you're shipping them to customers as part of your product, why not just have different execution policies in your dev and test environments?

Comment: I guess I am trying to "defend" against changes made to my code. I know it's not possible to lock down PowerShell completely, but I would like to ensure that I have at least made an effort to address the easy stuff as far as security. And, perhaps PowerShell means there isn't much to address, given that it is neither locked down not obfuscated and both modifying code and removing security measures is somewhat trivial.

Comment: If these are online users, you could offer "PowerShell as a service" using remote endpoints and [proxy functions to provide access only to call specific commands](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/03/use-delegated-administration-and-proxy-functions.aspx)

Comment: Not online. The tool is a software install and management tool that runs via shortcut or SCCM in an Admin User context, and then sets up a Registry "Run" to also run in user context and do software customization. All very specific to Autodesk software, which is, um, unique. ;)